# Get position of cell or text field in this cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a split view controller: view & tableview. In this table view I have custom cells with text field. I don't know how many cells will I have, so it generate automatically. And now I'm trying scroll to textfield, when it becomeFirstResponder. I've tried something like this:

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    CGPoint focusOnTextField = CGPointMake(0, 300 + textField.frame.origin.y);
    [scroller setContentOffset: focusOnTextField animated: YES];
}
```

300px - start position of my TableView. All seems alright, but `textField.frame.origin.y` always equal to 0 (like and `bounds.origin.y` btw).

I thought I can solve a problem if get position of cell, which textfield is active, and then replace `textField.frame.origin.y` on `cell.frame.origin.y` or something like this.

**===================================================================**

I forgot say that my tableviews scroll is disabled. I follow your advices and code examples and solve it like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellWithSubview:(UIView *)subview {

    while (subview && ![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]])
        subview = subview.superview;
    return (UITableViewCell *)subview;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *activeCell = [self cellWithSubview:textField];

    float offsetValueY = 200 + activeCell.origin.y;
    CGPoint focusOnTextField = CGPointMake(0, offsetValueY);
    [scroller setContentOffset:focusOnTextField animated:YES];
}
```

And know what? It's working! :-) But it create a new problem. When I begin editing textfield, scroller at first jump on top, and only then going to it correct position. When I write `[scroller setContentOffset:focusOnTextField animated:NO];` and this problem disappear, but there is no smooth move of scroller. And this is bad to me :-) So how we can solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how to scroll to a cell containing a text field ...

```
// find the cell containing a subview.  this works independently of how cells
// have been constructed.

- (UITableViewCell *)cellWithSubview:(UIView *)subview {

    while (subview && ![subview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]])
        subview = subview.superview;
    return (UITableViewCell *)subview;
}
```

Your idea is correct to trigger that action when editing begins.  Just do it using the cell...

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // find the cell containing this text field
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellWithSubview:textField];

    // now scroll using that cell's index path as the target
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add the textfield in the `UITableVieCell` content view (added by default if you are using .xib) then you have to call something like `textField.superview.superview` and this will give you the parent cell. If you add the text field directly to the cell view then you have to `textField.superview`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[tableView scrollToRowContainingComponent:textField atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

after adding the following category to UITableView:

```
@implementation UITableView (MyCategory)

-(NSIndexPath*)indexPathOfCellComponent:(UIView*)component {
    if([component isDescendantOfView:self] && component != self) {
        CGPoint point = [component.superview convertPoint:component.center toView:self];
        return [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(void)scrollToRowContainingComponent:(UIView*)component atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathOfCellComponent:component];
    if(indexPath) {
        [self scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: scrollPosition animated:animated];
    }
}

@end
```